# Make selected dropdown in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

My data is coming from database and want to make dropdown selected in angular.

Payment status coming from database and field name is payment_status
For Ex- if payment status is PENDING then selected Payment Pending otherwise Payment Received

Here is my code.

```
<div ng-repeat="product in data" class="order-received animated fadein delay-1">
<div class="order-header">
  <img class="avatar rectangle" src="img/user4.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="order-author">
    <span style="color:#cc0066;">{{product.GLname}} - {{product.mobno}}</span>
    <span class="small">Item - {{product.item_name}} ({{product.item_code}})</span>
    <span class="small">Qty - {{product.pqty}} Amt - Rs. {{product.rate}}</span>
    <select class="browser-default" style="margin-bottom:8px;" ng-model="paymentOption">
      <option value="RECEIVED">Payment Received</option>
      <option value="PENDING">Payment Pending</option>
    </select>
    <select class="browser-default" ng-model="orderOption">
      <option value="NEW">New Order</option>
      <option value="PROCESS">In Progress</option>
      <option value="SENT">Sent</option>
      <option value="DELIVERED">Delivered</option>
      <option value="CANCELLED">Cancelled</option>
    </select>               
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help!!!

Comment: What do you mean by make dropdown selected in Angular? You want to have a default selected option in your `select` element?

Comment: On what rules are you selecting a default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the `model` value to display something in the select

Since you said that you have field `payment_status`, you can use

**`ng-model="product.payment_status"`**

Here is the html,

```
<div ng-repeat="product in data" class="order-received animated fadein delay-1">
<div class="order-header">
  <img class="avatar rectangle" src="img/user4.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="order-author">
    <span style="color:#cc0066;">{{product.GLname}} - {{product.mobno}}</span>
    <span class="small">Item - {{product.item_name}} ({{product.item_code}})</span>
    <span class="small">Qty - {{product.pqty}} Amt - Rs. {{product.rate}}</span>
    <select class="browser-default" style="margin-bottom:8px;" ng-model="product.payment_status">
      <option value="RECEIVED">Payment Received</option>
      <option value="PENDING">Payment Pending</option>
    </select>
    <select class="browser-default" ng-model="orderOption">
      <option value="NEW">New Order</option>
      <option value="PROCESS">In Progress</option>
      <option value="SENT">Sent</option>
      <option value="DELIVERED">Delivered</option>
      <option value="CANCELLED">Cancelled</option>
    </select>               
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Arvind, check my answer

Comment: @ArvindJaiswal, GLad to help you. you can accept my answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You just define `paymentOption` value in controller :

as like  in controller

```
$scope.paymentOption = success.payment_status // value fetch from database
```

Answer (score -1):

You should set "paymentOption" to one of the values in the Select in the controller.